# c# datagridview search for maximum value between 2 rowindex

Tags: c#, datagridview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wlsvw.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFewC.jpg)

hi i have some questions

1 : how to convert a datetime to a simple number like 20180125

2 : i have a datagridview and one of the column is Date , for example i want search for maximum value in other column (age) since 2015/02/31 to 2017/02/31

in my opinion first i search for datetime value and get rowIndex , then search for maximum value in other column (age) by rowinder like 290 - 350, maybe better way ? like directly with datetimes var
if my question not clear i put more info

```
string rowdate = Convert.ToString(startofMonth); 


        DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(rowdate, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        String searchValue = "20180103"; //Datetime Example
        int rowIndex = -1;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells["date"].Value != null) // Need to check for null if new row is exposed
            {
                if (row.Cells["date"].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
                {
                    rowIndex = row.Index;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(rowIndex); //Show in textbox
    }
```

Comment: You definitely should compare DateTimes using types, not using strings.

Comment: hello igor , indeed but it was for search the rowIndex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 : how to convert a datetime to a simple number like 20180125
=> You can convert DateTime to a string using `.ToString("format")`
    For example:

```
Console.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
```

2: You can compare 2 `DateTime` values using < and > operators

***Update on Mar 13 based on your screenshot.*** (*You still need to do validation and exception handling*)

```
            //set start and end date
            DateTime fromThisDate = new DateTime(2015, 02, 21, 0, 0, 0);
            DateTime toThisDate = new DateTime(2017, 02, 21, 0, 0, 0);

            int indexOfMaximumAge = -1;
            int currentMaximumAge = -1;

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells[1].Value != null) // Need to check for null if new row is exposed
                {
                    //filter by date range
                    //convert
                    DateTime cellDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[1].Value); 
                    if ((cellDate > fromThisDate) & (cellDate < toThisDate))
                    {
                        //find max
                        //convert
                        int cellAge = Convert.ToInt16(row.Cells[3].Value);
                        if (cellAge > currentMaximumAge)
                        {
                            currentMaximumAge = cellAge;
                            indexOfMaximumAge = row.Index;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: hi AndyLe can u check the screenshots ? i upload on previous question

Comment: You have to notice a few things:
1. You can compare the `DateTime` values directly, no need to convert them to string value
2. My example is to give you the idea only. You did not include structure of your `DataGridView`, I cannot give you the exact code